# Jedis Bad file descriptor error

Tags: redis, jedis

I am writing to a redis database, by reading some data from text files. The code runs in a loop and adds to the database. The program runs fine for some time, but then I get the following runtime error.

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: 
java.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor (Write failed)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:334)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:263)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.rpush(Jedis.java:865)
    at clustering_words.SimilarWords.addSimilarWordsToRedis(SimilarWords.java:25)
    at clustering_words.SimilarWords.main(SimilarWords.java:77)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:52)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flush(RedisOutputStream.java:216)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:331)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A commenter on this other question reports the same error, and it turns out to have been caused by hitting the open files limit:
https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1#comment1729272_1171028